# Sort DataFrame asc/desc based on column value

Tags: pandas

I have this DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 100, 300, 200, 200, 200], 'B': [60, 55, 12, 32, 15, 44], 'C': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']})
```

and I want to sort it by columns "A" and "B". "A" is always ascending. I also want ascending for "B" if "C == x", else descending for "B" if "C == y". So it would end up like this

```
df_sorted = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300], 'B': [55, 60, 44, 32, 15, 12], 'C': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']})
```

Comment: We can filter the `df` for `C == x` first and sort the values in ascending order and then perform another filter for `C == y` and sort values in descending order. Is there a way to combine the two operations into one?

Answer (score 1):

I would filter each DataFrame into two Dataframe based on the value of C:

```
df_x = df.loc[df['C'] == 'x']
df_y = df.loc[df['C'] == 'y']
```

and then use "sort_values" like so:

```
df_x.sort_values(by=['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
```

sorting df_y will be different since you want one column ascending and the other descending, since "sort_values" is stable we can do it like so

```
df_y.sort_values(by=['A'], inplace=True)
df_y.sort_values(by=['b'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

You can then merge the DataFrames back and sort again by A and the order will remain.

Comment: If you found this comment helpful, please consider up-voting and\or marking as accepeted

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a temporary column to invert the values of "B" when "C" equals "x", sort, and drop the column:

```
(df.assign(B2=df['B']*df['C'].eq('x').mul(2).sub(1))
   .sort_values(by=['A', 'B2'])
   .drop('B2', axis=1)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.sort_values(['A','B']) if dd.name=='x' else dd.sort_values(['A','B'],ascending=[True,False])

df.groupby('C').apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)

     A   B  C
0  100  55  x
1  100  60  x
2  200  44  y
3  200  32  y
4  200  15  y
5  300  12  y
```